# Passing a char array from c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a dll of the LZ4 c implementation and I want to call the

```
LZ4_compress_default(const char* source,char* dest,int sourceLength,int maxdestLength);
```

function from a c# code. The function compresses the source array into the dest array. How to do this?

My C# code:

```
DllImport(@"CXX.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
internal static extern int LZ4_compress_default(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] char[] source, out byte[] dest, 
    int sourceSize, int maxDestSize); 


byte[] result= new byte[maxSize]; 
int x = LZ4_compress_default(array, out result, size, maxSize);
```

Comment: Should be unsigned char*. What aspect of this can't you do.

Comment: Having problem to pass the dest array by reference.The compressed array is written by the dll.But I am not getting the change in the c# side.

Comment: `[Out] byte[] dest` and obviously you need to allocate `dest` before you call the function

Comment: [DllImport(@"CXX.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] internal static extern int LZ4_compress_default([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] char[] source, out byte[] dest, int sourceSize, int maxDestSize);

Comment: byte[] result= new byte[maxSize];
  int x = LZ4_compress_default(array, out result, size, maxSize);

Comment: I am using the above calls. But now I am getting access violation exceptio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code has a number of mistakes:

- It is pointless to set `CharSet` since there is no text here.
- You specify `SetLastError` as `true` but I doubt that your C function does call the Win32 `SetLastError` function.
- In C# `char` is a 2 byte text holding a UTF-16 character element. That does not batch C `char` or `unsigned char` which are 8 bit types.
- Your code expects the C function to allocate a managed `byte[]`, because the byte array is declared as an `out` parameter. Your C code cannot allocate a managed `byte[]`. Instead you need to have the caller allocate the array. So the parameter must be `[Out] byte[] dest`.

The C code should use `unsigned char` rather than `char` because you are operating on binary rather than text. It should be:

```
int LZ4_compress_default(const unsigned char* source, unsigned char* dest,
    int sourceLength, int maxDestLength);
```

The matching C# p/invoke is:

```
[DllImport(@"...", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
static extern int LZ4_compress_default(
    [In] byte[] source, 
    [Out] byte[] dest, 
    int sourceLength, 
    int maxDestLength
);
```

Call it like this:

```
byte[] source = ...;
byte[] dest = new byte[maxDestLength]; 
int retval = LZ4_compress_default(source, dest, source.Length, dest.Length); 
// check retval for errors
```

I've guessed at the return type of the function because you omitted that in the C declaration, but your C# code suggests that it is `int`.

Comment: I have posted the code.I am wondering why I am getting access violation exception

Comment: Because your code has various errors as I described. My final bullet point is the most plausible reason for an AV. I'm guessing that you perhaps don't realise that `out byte[] dest` and `[Out] byte[] dest` are completely different.

Comment: Yes I missed that.Thanks.That was a great help. Thanks a lot. I am not familiar with c# so i was facing the issue.Thanks a lot.