# How to call a function from DLL in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

There is code (one of) in C:

```
     void Function(char *output, size_t size);
```

There is code in C#:

```
    [DllImport(@"C:\path\Name.dll",
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
                CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Function")]
    static extern void Function([In, Out] StringBuilder output,
                                [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] UIntPtr size);
```

And if I call this function app fails with this error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'C:\path\Name.dll': Access denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

What is wrong? What must I do?

Comment: You have two issues 1) You have to allocate the the variable output before calling the DLL. char[] output = new char[256]();  2) A char in c# is two bytes while in c it is one byte.  Usually you should use byte[] instead of char[].

Comment: @jdweng If I call another method without params app fails with this error. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146181/passing-a-char-array-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll.  Use byte[] instead of char[].  Don't use String Builder.

Comment: Although there can be other issues, the reason for "Access denied" error is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381582/how-to-create-a-full-trust-uwp-app

Answer (score 0):

Add the DLL in your project and set it as content type copied in the output directory. Then reference it this way (do not add the extension ".dll" :

```
 [DllImport(@"Name",
                CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
                CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "Function")]
    static extern void Function([In, Out] StringBuilder output,
                                [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] UIntPtr size);
```

This is what is done by SqlLite (example : https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs ) :)

As pointed out by jdweng, you may want to use byte[] instead of StringBuilder too.

Comment: App can't find dll if I write this: [DllImport(@"Name". If I write [DllImport(@"../Name" app fails with old error. I don't know what I should do(

Comment: May be DLL use API that wasn't implemented in UWP? (This DLL isn't my creation)

Comment: I don't know for this. Maybe it's the calling convention which need to be changed. Try to use CallingConvention.Cdecl maybe ?

Comment: I am sorry, Can't help you more without your dll, I hope you will find an answer :)