# Get Windows.Storage.StorageFile object without using StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

[`StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync?view=winrt-19041#windows-storage-storagefile-getfilefrompathasync(system-string)) API fails if file is hidden file or a shortcut even if UWP/Win32 app can access to these locations using other APIs (i.e. [`...FromApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapifromapp/nf-fileapifromapp-createfilefromappw) APIs although they have some limitation too). For Win32 apps it is possible to get an [`IShellItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) object and [bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler#bhid_storage) it to [`IStorageItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.istorageitem?view=winrt-20348) but in UWP it is not possible as `IShellItem` isn't available for UWP. Is there any other way I can bypass `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` restrictions to get `StorageFile` object that can be done with UWP app model?

Comment: Have you tried with advanced capabilities? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381582/how-to-create-a-full-trust-uwp-app otherwise it's doubtful you can bypass the sandbox.

Comment: @SimonMourier I am not talking about bypassing sandbox limitations, I am talking about bypassing  limitation for this specific `StorageFile` API. As I have already mentioned app has already permission to access these locations and I can already read/write with other UWP APIs. What I want is using `StorageFile` specific API.

Comment: If you can't get an IShellItem from UWP, that's what I call sandbox limitation...

Comment: If the system file explorer enables **showing hidden files**, then you could use **FileOpenPicker** to get the hidden files as a StorageFile Object. And if the system file explorer doesn't enable showing hidden files, then the FileOpenPicker won't see it as well. So using the **FileOpenPicker** could be an option for you if you don't mind the limitation.