# How do I put a C program in a C# UWP?

Tags: c#, c, dll, uwp, static-libraries

I am creating a Windows 10 application that works with files. For the GUI I am using UWP (C#) and for the file processing I want to use the C language (Visual Studio 2019).

I have tried these solutions (none of them worked):

1. C program created with Windows Desktop Wizard (DLL), then DllImport

Tried to add it to the UWP by using DllImport (which in a C# Console App program worked).

The code in the C file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

_declspec(dllexport) int getNumberOfFiles()
{
    ...
}
```

The code in the C# UWP app:

```
 [DllImport(@"...\WorkFilesDll\Debug\WorkFilesDll.dll", EntryPoint = "getNumberOfFiles", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 internal static extern int getNumberOfFiles();
```

The following exception is thrown:

> System.DllNotFoundException     HResult=0x80131524     Message=Unable
> to load DLL '...\WorkFilesDll\Debug\WorkFilesDll.dll' or one of its
> dependencies: Access is denied.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
> (E_ACCESSDENIED))

2. C program created with Windows Desktop Wizard (DLL), then add as reference

Tried to add the same dll as reference (References->Add Reference->Browse->Add->OK).
After pressing the OK button, the following message indicates the failure:

> A reference to "...\WorkFilesDll\Debug\WorkFilesDll.dll" could not be
> added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is a
> valid assembly or COM component.

3. I created other types of projects for the C code (C++, UWP):  Dll (Universal Windows), Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows). The results were the same.
4. I created other types of projects (C#, UWP): Class Library (Universal Windows), Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows), in order to add theses projects to the UWP and to add to these projects the dll mentioned above (the C code to be added indirectly to the UWP). The results were the same.

I have found many questions and articles like this, but I didn't see a clear answer or the answers didn't work for me. Some of them are:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/dlls-c-cx?view=msvc-160
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-use-cpp-dlls-in-c-sharp-uwp-projects
- [How to call a function from DLL in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508279/how-to-call-a-function-from-dll-in-uwp)
- [Can you use C++ DLLs in C# code in a UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489924/can-you-use-c-dlls-in-c-sharp-code-in-a-uwp)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160

I have also read about static libraries. I have failed in implementing them.

**How can I put the C code in UWP (C#)?**

**Are static libraries the answer to my application?**

**Which are better for this application: the DLLs or the static libraries? Why?**

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this? It seems you are making it complicated for no good reason. C# can do file handling. C++ can do GUI. Why insist on mixing them and have more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: Yes. I want to use C# for the GUI and C for processing (not C++). C provides better processing of files (access to some files, speed etc.). I want to use C# for the GUI because it seems to me that the GUIs created with UWP (C#) are better than those in C++.

Comment: It should success if you follow the guide from the last link. The real problem here is UWP prohibit some Win32 API that why you got `E_ACCESSDENIED`.

Comment: As far as I know, UWP does not support to run libraries that depend on a specific system.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon For the static libraries or for the DLLs?

Comment: Please try with a C++ DLL for UWP, not Desktop.

Comment: I have tried to create a C++ DLL for UWP. Only the C# DLLs for UWP work. Those in C++ give the same errors mentioned in the question. The project type of the DLL that I created for the UWP is DLL (Universal Windows), C++.

Comment: You could try to convert library into a **Windows Runtime Component** to expose functionality to callers in other languages. **Windows Runtime Components** differ from ordinary DLLs in that they include metadata in the form of .winmd files that describe the contents in a way that .NET and JavaScript consumers require.
You could refer to [Porting a C++ Library to a Windows Runtime Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160#BK_WinRTComponent) for more information.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I have created a C++ Windows Runtime Component, but I need pure C. I tried to create a Windows Runtime Component in pure C and failed.

Comment: In C++ Windows Runtime Component, you could refer to the DLL (which contains your pure C code) , just by using **Add Reference** option. And in C# UWP project, refer to the C++ Windows Runtime Component by using **Add Reference** option. Add a `#include` statement such as `#include "..\MyDll1\MyDll1.h" ` in C++ Windows Runtime Component project.

Comment: Store the value calculated by using C code in a methods(such as the auto-generated `MyProperty` method of `Class` class) of C++ Windows Runtime Component, and call the methods of C++ Windows Runtime Component in C# UWP project. If you need, I can show you a small sample with code.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT A small sample with code would help me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following steps:

1. Create a **C# UWP** project in a new solution.
2. Add a C++ **DLL(Universal Windows)** project(named `MyDll1`) in the same solution.
3. Add your C code in the C++ DLL project. For example:

```
//MyDll1.h
#pragma once

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int Sum(int a, int b);

//MyDll1.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyDll1.h"
int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

4. Add a **Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)** project in the same project.
5. Right-click on the name of the **Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)** project, and select option **Add > Reference**, check your DLL project in **Projects** tab. Click **OK**.
6. There is an auto-generated class `Class`, you could use the class or add other class(**Add > New Item > Code > Midl File(.idl)**) as needed. The new class must be generated from a **midl** file. You could get more information about authoring api referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis#if-youre-authoring-a-runtime-class-in-a-windows-runtime-component).
7. Take `Class` class as an example. Include the header file of dll in `Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)` project.

```
//Class.h
#include "..\MyDll1\MyDll1.h"
```

8. There is a sample method named `MyProperty` shown in `Class` class. The `MyProperty`  method is added to the `Class.idl` file and the complier will generate the corresponding methods in `Class.h` and `Class.cpp` after you build the project. And you need to go to the locations `\RuntimeComponent\ RuntimeComponent \Generated Files\sources\Class.h` and `Class.cpp` in **File Explorer** and open the .h and .cpp file to copy the generated methods into your code in Visual Studio. You could use `MyProperty` method to pass values to C# project or add other methods in classes. Refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/intro) for more information about how to add new method in idl file.
9. You could call the `Sum(int a, int b)` of `MyDll1` project in `MyProperty` method.

```
int32_t Class::MyProperty()
{
    int t = Sum(1, 2);
    return t;
}
```

10. Right-click on the name of the C# UWP project, and select option **Add > Reference**, check your **Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)** project in **Projects**. Click **OK**.
11. Add include statement in C# UWP project.

```
using RuntimeComponent;   // RuntimeComponent is the name of Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT) project.
```

12. You could call the `MyProperty` method in C# UWP project.

```
RuntimeComponent.Class myClass = new Class();
var value = myClass.MyProperty;
```

Comment: By much testing, I let the C# UWP project refer to C++ DLL(Universal Windows) successfully. You need to set two options in dll's Properties. Please set the option **Properties > C/C++ > General > Consume Windows Runtime Extension** as **Yes(/ZW)** and set the option 
**Properties > Linker > Windows Metadata > Generate Windows Metadata** as **Yes(/WINMD)**. If exists error about `EntryPoint`, then you could find the `dllMain.cpp` file and delete the `switch` statement in `Main()`.

Comment: The code in dll can be similar to this:  

extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) Sum(int a, int b)
{
 return (a + b);
}

And the importing code in uwp project like this: 

[DllImport("DllName.dll",EntryPoint = "Sum")]
private static extern int Sum(int a, int b);

If you are using Visual Studio 2019, note to set the Platform of uwp project and dll project as x64.